Cannot create relation(table) in my postgresql database
I'm trying to create a Spring Boot API and connect it to a simple Postgresql database that I have created . I am connecting to a local server. I'm trying to set up the connection so that my table is created in the database I want. Every time I do so and I go back to my SQL Shell, I find that there is no relation in my database, meaning the table is never actually created.
The username I have set up is my name, and the database name I have set up is student. Every time I go into the student database, there is no relation. However, whenever I go into the Postgres database(owned by Postgres user) I am able to find the relation that I was trying to create in my student database. What could be the reason for this.
Also, I have configured my application.properties file to work with my username and the student database. But every time I rerun the Spring Boot application, it changes it the configurations back to the Postgres username and the Postgres database.
I tried using the table annotation to specify the name of the table I would like associated with my class. That didn't do anything. I've restarted my IDE multiple times. That hasn't done anything. I am not getting any errors or exceptions, just cannot find the relation where I want it to be
[forced configuration][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/4atSZSAL.png
[desired configuration][2]
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/lTWDob9F.png

Share your application.properties file.

update
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

TO
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

You can also use :
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop : when application start hibernate generate database schema and drop hole database schema when application shut down.
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update : It update database schema as current entity mapping.
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none : This setting do not create any change in db.Developer have to create db with manual query.Generally in production this setting used.
As you do not see any error.Check logging level what hibernate doing.
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG

add this in your application.properties
Your application.properties modified  :
spring.application.name=project
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=<YOUR DATABASE NAME>
spring.datasource.password=<YOUR PASSWORD>
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true


i put up a pic of my application.properties

update spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop to spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
